# Show that any bounded, nonempty set of natural numbers has a maximal element

Tags: real-analysis, induction, solution-verification

This is question 1 from section 1.8 of this textbook http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Portrait.pdf

I am just wondering if my proof here is valid or if I'm missing any key information.

Assume S is a bounded, nonempty set of natural numbers. We will use induction on n, the number of elements in S to show that a bounded, nonempty set of natural numbers has a maximal element. If S has one element, say $S=${x}, them $maxS = x \in S$. Assume our assertion about bounded, nonempty sets of natural numbers is true for k elements with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. If S has k+1 elements, then $S_1 = S/${x} has k elements. Since $S_1$ has k elements and by our induction hypothesis, it must have a maximum which we will call $y \in S_1$. So the maximum of S must be the max{$S_1 \cup x$} = max{y, x}. Since $y \in S_1 \subseteq S$, it follows that $y \in S$ and $x \in S$. Therefore max{y,x} $\in S$ and thus every bounded, nonempty set of natural numbers has a maximum.

Comment: Sounds good to me :)

Comment: How do you know that a bounded set of natural numbers is finite? You should also clarify the use of $x$, e.g., "let $x$ be an arbitrary element in $S$".